# Ubuntu Eoan: release does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, updates, files, release-management

I've got the following errors below, the release files appear to be missing from the website:

```
Ign:1 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Ign:2 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease
Err:4 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.248 80]
Err:5 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.248 80]
Err:6 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.248 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

If I list via the web, I can't find release/release.gpg:

```
Index of /ubuntu/dists/eoan
[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size
[PARENTDIR] Parent Directory        -
[   ]   Contents-amd64.gz   2019-10-30 13:28    39M
[   ]   Contents-arm64.gz   2019-10-30 14:58    38M
[   ]   Contents-armhf.gz   2019-10-30 15:27    37M
[   ]   Contents-i386.gz    2019-10-30 15:57    38M
[   ]   Contents-ppc64el.gz 2019-10-30 16:30    37M
[   ]   Contents-s390x.gz   2019-10-30 16:57    37M
[DIR]   by-hash/    2019-04-18 14:33    -
[DIR]   main/   2019-10-10 19:18    -
[DIR]   multiverse/ 2019-04-24 12:08    -
[DIR]   restricted/ 2019-04-24 08:08    -
[DIR]   universe/   2019-04-24 09:13    -
```

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/07/17/ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2020/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: This is a known issue.  See discussion in comments under https://askubuntu.com/q/1299193/816190 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1299151/816190 but *eoan* is now off-topic here because it's EOL.

Comment: FYI for support-helpers here, asked again on IRC, and whilst I've not raised bug report yet, I've asked on community (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/no-release-file-for-eoan-in-old-releases-ubuntu-com/19817) now too

Comment: Try: http://archive.canonical.com/dists/eoan/

Comment: This worked for me : https://askubuntu.com/a/1299645/649516