# Ubuntu 19.10 eoan apt update error

Tags: apt, updates, 19.10

This looks different from other reported problems because last week it was just ok.

When running sudo apt update I get get this errors:

```
Err:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
Err:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
Err:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
Err:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
```

and...

```
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Right now I can’t upgrade to the LTS 20.04 focal because I’m working on something with this laptop, so I’m wondering if this is a temporary error or if there is a solution.

Comment: That's does not look like an error. It's expected behavior for a release of Ubuntu that is well past End Of Life. There have been no updates to 19.10 for months.

Comment: Limit what you do on that laptop to only what you need. when finish, upgrade or install to 20.04.  Know that without updates, security holes might be present.  Would use another updated laptop for any other internet use.

Comment: If one still needs to install some packages from 19.10 (eoan) without switching to a supported branch, one can change the address to <http://old-releases.ubuntu.com> from <http://archive.ubuntu.com> in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, as in <https://askubuntu.com/a/1300036/19753>

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev -- this works for standard installs; for some reason my setup had http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ instead of the standard archive address ... but changing to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ seems to have worked anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseNotes

Ubuntu 19.10 is supported for 9 months until July 2020.

You'll need to upgrade your ubuntu version

```
Upgrading from Ubuntu 19.04

To upgrade on a desktop system:

    Open the "Software & Updates" application.
    Select the 3rd Tab called "Updates".
    Set the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" dropdown menu to "For any new version".
    Press Alt+F2 and type in "update-manager -c -d" (without the quotes) into the command box.
    Update Manager should open up and tell you: New distribution release '19.10' is available.
        If not you can also use "/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk" 
    Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions. 

To upgrade on a server system:

    Install the update-manager-core package if it is not already installed.

    Make sure the Prompt line in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades is set to Prompt=normal.

    Launch the upgrade tool with the command do-release-upgrade.
    Follow the on-screen instructions. 

Note that the server upgrade will use GNU screen and automatically re-attach in case of dropped connection problems.

There are no offline upgrade options for Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server. Please ensure you have network connectivity to one of the official mirrors or to a locally accessible mirror and follow the instructions above.

Upgrades on i386

Users of the i386 architecture will not be presented with an upgrade to Ubuntu 19.10. Support for i386 as a host architecture is dropped in 19.10.
```

Comment: This is December 2020 so July 2020 has come and gone

Comment: Ok. I understand that. Thanks for all your answers.
Because I still have a ‘Trusty’ 14.04 LST connected to my tv as a media center and didn’t ever get such errors and still have some updates, I was wondering why I get this on ‘eoan’. Maybe that’s because ‘Trusty’ was LTS.
I’ll do a ‘Focal’ fresh install as soon as I can.

Comment: indeed - you can see the different ubuntu releases here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases